# Facebook Dialog Request ie9 &10 sec7111 error message

Tags: facebook, ssl, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I developed a Facebook_App where you can invite your friends by a Requests Dialog. It works fine for Firefox and Chrome, but in ie9 and 10 users get a "mixed Content warning" and cannot click on the share button, if they confirm the message the app is reloaded and they have to start from the beginning. If I debbug with ie developer Tools I get this error message:

> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
>   http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?.....
>
> SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by
>   http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=X

Has anyone an idea why? Here is my code:

```
 <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>       
        <div id="container" class="page004">
            <div id="share"><input class="btn_send" type="button" onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;" value="" /></div> 


    <script>

    FB.init({
        appId  : 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
        frictionlessRequests: true
    });

    function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', message: 'MESSAGE'}, requestCallback);
    }

    function requestCallback(response) {
        window.location = "referer.php";
    }

    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are you calling that page using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I call the page with https and it works, but some users didn't activate https in Facebook. Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: Is you app available via HTTP also? To load the SDK the correct way in both cases, don’t prefix the URL with the protocol, but do it as shown in the docs instead.

Comment: Yes it's also avaiable via HTTP

Comment: Well then try loading the SDK without the explicit protocol.

Comment: i tryed to load the SDK without explicit protocoll, after that it worked for http but not for https. But due to your answer i started to sarch if i can read the url with php or javascript. Now i check the browser url, and depending on the protcoll, I link to a page with/without explicit sdk loading. Donn't know if there's a better way. But it works for me. Thanks a lot CBroe for your quick answer.